# PIC18f8722 interrupt problem

Tags: pic, interrupts

I did many research but couldn't find out what the problem it is. Actually my code as below. I am trying to implement a code in  C with XC8 compiler.

To enable a sentence on the LCD of the board while RB6 button is pressed. I enable INCTONbits.GIE = 1 and INTCONbits.RBIE = 1 and INTCONbits.RBIF = 0.

Inside of interrupt, the displaySentence() function is entered to infinity loop to see result. I checked all answers related with interrupt in here but didn't help my problem. What can be problem for RB7-4 interrupt, I am working on [PIC18f8722](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39646c.pdf).

```
void displaySentence();

void initialize();


void interrupt  RBINT_ISR(void){

    INTCONbits.GIE = 0;

 __delay_ms(10);

    while(1){
        displaySentence();
    }
    INTCONbits.RBIF = 0;
    INTCONbits.RBIE = 1;
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
}


void main(void)
{
    __delay_ms(15);
    __delay_ms(15);
    __delay_ms(15);
    __delay_ms(15);

    InitLCD();          // Initialize LCD in 4bit mode
    ClearLCDScreen();  // Clear LCD screen

    initialize();

    while(1);
}



void initialize(){

    TRISB = 0x40;
    PORTB = 0x00;

    // | GIE/GIEH | PEIE/GIEL | TMR0IE  | INT0IE | RBIE | TMR0IF | INT0IF | RBIF
    // |   1      |    0      |  0      |  0     |   1  |   0    |    0   |  0
    INTCONbits.RBIF = 0;
    INTCONbits.RBIE = 1;
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
}

void displaySentence(){

    WriteCommandToLCD(0x80);
    WriteStringToLCD("Interrupt");
    WriteCommandToLCD(0xC0);
    WriteStringToLCD("is working");
}
```

Comment: Does the LCD work to display strings from main()? How are you triggering the PortB interrupt? How are your PortB pins connected?

Comment: Yes LCD works correctly inside the main,I need to control RB6  button with PORTB change interrupt. I need
to enable pull-up.

Comment: Have you enabled PortB pullups somewhere or do you have external pullup resistors? I don't see anything like a "INTCON2bits.RBPU = 0;" anywhere in your code to enable the internal pullups.

Comment: I didn't use "INTCON2bits.RBPU = 0;" but while using it directly goes to interrupt.It may be due to external pull up resistors.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @brhans for your answer I did as you said. I disabled `INTCON2bits.RBPU = 0` and it worked for me.